# OS X El Capitan , Developer Tools installed but not working

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, gcc, osx-elcapitan

I recently updated to El Capitan . i installed the latest non-beta XCode and the command line tools using `xcode-select --install`. although the tools are installed i dont seem to be able to use any of them. trying to run gcc from the terminal causes the following output :

`sh: line 1:  1849 Trace/BPT trap: 5       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk / -find gcc 2> /dev/null
gcc: error: unable to find utility "gcc", not a developer tool or in PATH`

i noticed that git is working but still none of the make, g++ or other C/CPP related stuff seem to work.

any help is appreciated !

Comment: That breakpoint trap indicates that something is definitely broken in your environment. Do you, by any chance, have any of the `DYLD_` environment variables set? They may be pointing to a dodgy library/directory

Comment: @Petesh , Ahh ! that fixed it , i had this : `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/Parsoa/code/llvm/build/Debug+Asserts/lib:/Users/Parsoa/code/libomp_oss/exports/mac_32e/lib.thin` .i commented the line and exported the PATH again , now everything seems to work .

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Can you tell me where can I find that `DYLD_` thing?